# Image inside flexbox squeezed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a div and I placed an image on it, the div is full width with overflow hidden, the image is bigger than the screen and it works perfectly because it doesn't create the scrollbars, the thing is that I want to use that div as flexbox, but something weird happened, the image was squeezed. I opened it on IE and it was working, but it was working because IE doesn't wrap the content if it's bigger than the size of the wrapper, and we need to add `flex-wrap`, but I wouldn't because IE was working the way I wanted just like the div with the overflow hidden, I tried to add `flex-wrap: nowrap;` in other to force firefox/chrome/opera to work like IE, but it doens't.

How can I make flexbox to don't squeeze the image on firefox/chrome/opera?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://teleseries.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Friends_S3_00233601_7a717bd.jpeg" alt="..."/>
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[You can see it here](http://output.jsbin.com/qohafoluya/3/)

Comment: Well this is sort of a dirty fix but you could manually set the images width in the html as 100%. I.E. adding   style="width:100%"   to the image element.

Comment: Actually I didn't find it dirty, it kinda worked here, but it would be a problem with small images. The other problem is about resizing images on the browser is not recommended. - I will wait for other answer, if nobody help besides you, I will stick with that one. Thank you.

Comment: I just found a problem, the image with full width doesn't get the wanted height, and if I put the height it squeezes again.

Comment: This being asked many times, however I have not seen any good solution yet, can you use background image instead? means the wrapper has to have a height, or just drop flex.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution either. I think that flexbox should be like in IE in this case, without wrapping and if the person wants to wrap just use `flex-wrap` and done. I dropped flexbox in this case and used position absolute and relative to position the image and other things.

Comment: Flexbox is great to get some kind work jobs done easily, but it's not that reliable comes to cross browser compatibility. Feel free to post if you have other questions, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want but I think you want full image shows up as in IE and in the center not squeezed if so here is the code if not can you please explain more and I will try to get it for you.

```
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     }

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper > img{
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      position: relative;
}
```

### let me know because I'm interesting in this tipic